# Installing/Running CGAL on Ubuntu

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-14.04, cgal

I can't seem to install CGAL properly on my computer. I'm using Ubuntu, and I ran these commands, like it says to do in the directions.

```
sudo apt-get install libcgal-dev
sudo apt-get install libcgal-demo
```

They install fine, no errors. But then the directions say to cd into CGAL-4.7, but couldn't find it. I found a CGAL under /usr/include, and it seems to include all the algorithm files. But there are no MakeFile/CMakeLists to cmake.

I'm not sure what to do?

Comment: The explanation with `cd CGAL-4.7` is for installing manually, it isn't relevant since with the apt-get commands you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, once I found it, I tried this below and it worked

```
cd /path/to/program 
cgal_create_CMakeLists -s executable 
cmake -DCGAL_DIR=$HOME/CGAL-4.7 . 
make
```

Comment: You should remove that `-DCGAL_DIR=$HOME/CGAL-4.7`: that's not where you have CGAL installed if you used the Ubuntu package...

Comment: oh. Where is it installed?